# Restrict administrator to one store view

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, backend, administration, acl

I have installed and configured a Magento Community edition v1.8 according to a few requirements. Part of the requirements is the setup of a few stores.

For completion though, it is necessary to configure "administrators" per se for each of these stores. This administrator, when (s)he logs in to the admin portal, would be viewing data, configuration and settings only for their respective store, and the rest(of the stores) is not shown (As is the case when one configures an admin role via System -> Permissions -> Roles).

When the main administrator logs in to the back-end portal, they should view options for assigning these smaller (so to speak) administrators to their respective admin website sites. This list should be updated when stores are added/deleted (and hence the excellent Alan Storm's blog is not of much help)

I have been looking at various tutorials that enable and manipulate ACL, although none of them specifically tackle allowing such specific administrator access.

Can someone kindly point the right resources for achieving such a functionality? Any help is very much appreciated and will be repaid with karma points :)

(I forgot to mention that I am not looking for a turnkey solution, but rather a direction to proceed, so that I may configure it myself. Any resource in this regard will be very helpful!)

Answer (score -1):

Check whether [Advanced Permissions Module](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html) would be helpful to you to achieve your target.

Comment: please try to avoid link only answers. You can provide a short description of the content on that link here

Comment: Yes yes I already know of this particular module. Would be great if this can be achieved without any cost.

Comment: Should I remove that answer as I cannot put the Paid module files here as answer? If I'm going to explain it, I must share the code as well,right? Unfortunately I don’t have the code and the only way I found to answer this question was adding the link top the module page.